# Flutter Http Request: Invalid response status code

Tags: dart, flutter

I make an HTTP call in flutter for checking the username and password on my login page.
If I put the right username and password, I will get a status code of 200 OK! Everything is fine up to this point.

But if I put a wrong username and password, to get my status code 901 for that, flutter throws an exception: Invalid response status code!
Maybe the HTTP package just works with the regular status codes (not the individual ones)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely don't want to be returning 901. You should be returning a valid understood status code.  For example, I'd use 403 (Forbidden).  An easy-to-understand list can be found in the Wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes.

Comment: Thanks - you are right!
But is there any way, to create individual status codes, flutter also accepts?

Comment: I'd return the 403 code, and then the details in a header.  No reason *not* to use a 403 for Forbidden.

Comment: Login was just an example, but I have an use case, where I need to use an indiviual status code. So how can I handle this with flutter?

Comment: You need to map it into one of the official codes, with more data in the header to distinguish your subcases.

Answer (score 2):

You should return a valid http status code otherwise it will return the error you mentioned:

https://github.com/dart-lang/http/blob/master/lib/src/base_response.dart

Comment: Thanks, but do you know, if there is any way to work with custoized status codes?

Comment: Sure, you just have to create your own http client.